# Unable to close CD tray

Tags: ubuntu

I hope you can help me. I have an external (slim) Blu-Ray Drive, which is connected via USB. Whenever I open the drive, the activity-LED starts blinking fast, and I am unable to close the drive. When I try to close it, the tray is getting ejected immediately. I have to disconnect the USB to be able to close the tray.

This must be software-related problem, because I do not have this problem within Windows.
I have Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. There is an interesting line inside the syslog:

```
Sep 14 11:36:07 linux-gurke kernel: scsi 6:0:0:0: CD-ROM            PIONEER  BD-RW   BDR-UD04 1.11 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Sep 14 11:36:07 linux-gurke kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
Sep 14 11:36:07 linux-gurke kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 62x/62x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
Sep 14 11:36:07 linux-gurke kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
Sep 14 11:36:07 linux-gurke kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
Sep 14 11:36:13 linux-gurke kernel: usb 6-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
Sep 14 11:36:13 linux-gurke kernel: scsi 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to dead device
Sep 14 11:36:13 linux-gurke systemd-udevd[8161]: sr0: Process 'cdrom_id --eject-media /dev/sr0' failed with exit code 1.
```

The last line "eject media failed" is being written to syslog as soon as I disconnect the drive. So obviously, some process is trying to issue an eject / close tray command while the tray is open, which obviously cannot work, as it is a slim drive, you have to push the tray manually to close it.

Some information:

```
$> lsusb -s 006:005 -t
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
$> lsusb -s 006:005
Bus 006 Device 005: ID 18a5:0428 Verbatim, Ltd Verbatim 4K BD RW
```

Note that, the drive is manufactured by verbatim, but inside the syslog, it appears as a pioneer drive.

I already tried `echo 0 > /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/autoclose` and `echo 0 > /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/autoeject`, it did not make a difference. Can you guys help me identify the problem?

Comment: I had a similar problem with my CD drive, in particular after using an audio CD. It turned out the culprit was `udisk`, which wanted to automatically determine the filesystem, and ended up in a loop. After laboriously figuring out how to disable `udisk` (wasn't easy), the problem went away. This may or may not be related to your problem.

Comment: I was using audio-cds lately, so this might be my problem, too - what is udisk, and how can I disable it? Bute note that this problem also occurs when the drive is empty.

Comment: Yes, the problem also occured if the drive was empty (after I used an audio CD), and udev was also involved, though only in a secondary role - it's the udev rules that trigger udisk.

Comment: I googled a bit about udisk, and this does not sound like anything you want to disable under usual circumstances...

Comment: I have a very minimalist desktop, so I guess that counts for "unusual circumstances".

Answer (score 1):

I have found the bad guy causing the troubles. I noticed that whenever the activity LED was blinking fast, `systemd-udevd` was active with around 3% cpu time. This lead me to issuing the command `udevadm monitor -u` while inserting the CD and pressing the eject button (I marked the moment when I pressed the button with the `press` line):

```
$> udevadm monitor -u
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing

UDEV  [6294.187246] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2d:00.3/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
press
UDEV  [6319.266413] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2d:00.3/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
UDEV  [6319.393838] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2d:00.3/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
UDEV  [6319.481907] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2d:00.3/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
UDEV  [6319.574832] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2d:00.3/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
UDEV  [6319.672829] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2d:00.3/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
UDEV  [6319.770823] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2d:00.3/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
UDEV  [6319.868807] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2d:00.3/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
UDEV  [6319.966829] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2d:00.3/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
UDEV  [6320.064811] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2d:00.3/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
UDEV  [6320.163830] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2d:00.3/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
```

those change events kept apearing until I disconnected the device. After a little bit of research, I found the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules`, which contained the line:

```
# media eject button pressed
ENV{DISK_EJECT_REQUEST}=="?*", RUN+="cdrom_id --eject-media $devnode", GOTO="cdrom_end"
```

Remember the error which showed up in the syslog? I copied the file to `/etc/udev/rules.d` and changed the line to

```
ENV{DISK_EJECT_REQUEST}=="?*", GOTO="cdrom_end"
```

This immediately fixed my problem, although it created another: when pressing the eject button, nothing happened. But issuing an eject command with `eject /dev/sr0` worked, without the drive going crazy. (This command previously had the same effect like pressing the hardware eject button!)

This might be a bug inside the udev package, Although I cannot be sure of that. And my "fix" surely is only a workaround - something is creating the endless source of udev events which obviously is causing an immediate media eject, as soon as the tray is closed...

Maybe this is helpful for anybody else running inside this problem!